# How to add multiple operands to a MDNode or metadata in LLVM?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to create an MDNode pointer with multiple operands. The following code create an MDNode pointer with 1 operand:

```
llvm::MDNode *MDNOdeNVVM = llvm::MDNode::get(*context, llvm::MDString::get(*context, "kernel"));
```

But I dont see an addOperand function in LLVM Manual. So is there any function that will let me create metadata with multiple operands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `MDTuple`. First you create your operands in a vector and then you create the Tuple. Something like:

```
SmallVector<Metadata *, 32> Ops;
Ops.push_back(llvm::MDString::get(*context, "linux"));
Ops.push_back(llvm::MDString::get(*context, "kernel"));
auto *Node =  MDTuple::get(Context, Ops);
```